# $\frac{1}{p(T_{i-1},T_i)}(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+$ at time $T_i$ is equivalent to a payment of $(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+$ at time $T_{i-1}$

Tags: finance, bond, mathematics, financial

How can I show that payment of $\frac{1}{p(T_{i-1},T_i)}(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+$ at time $T_i$ is equivalent to a payment of $(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+$ at time $T_{i-1}$ ? Where A is a deterministic constant.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define the variable names you are using? It will make the question much more clear.

Comment: Hi @BobJansen sorry for my delay. The price at time $t$ of a bond with maturity date $T$ is denoted by $p(t,T)$ and $A$ is a deterministic constant.

Comment: Don't worry, I see you have your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the quantity $\frac{1}{p(T_{i-1},T_i)}(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+$ and the quantity $(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+$ are known at time $T_{i-1}$. Then the payment $\frac{1}{p(T_{i-1},T_i)}(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+$ at time $T_i$ discount back to time $T_{i-1}$ is the equivalent payment. That is
\begin{align*}
\bigg[\frac{1}{p(T_{i-1},T_i)}(A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+\bigg] \times p(T_{i-1},T_i) = (A-p(T_{i-1},T_i))^+,
\end{align*}
where $p(T_{i-1},T_i)$ is the discount factor.